# Как исправить ошибку при использовании @qiwi/bill-payments-node-js-sdk для выставления счёта?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, qiwi, p2p

У меня есть следующий код. Если что, это на Nestjs, но без types, поскольку не смог их найти. console.log(qiwiApi.createPaymentForm(QIWISettings)) выдаёт ссылку, я могу по ней перейти, но в итоге "Не хватает параметров для создания счета". Параметры практически скопированы из документации, и я не могу понять, что не так.

Если что, billId тоже нормальный генерируется - 7b51d777-5a8b-45a2-9cc5-846534df23ba

Кстати если я меняю SECRET_KEY на неправильный, то он тоже генерирует ссылку, и ошибка та же.

В чём проблема? Что сделать?

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PaymentRepository } from "./payment.repository";
import { RMQService } from "nestjs-rmq";
import QiwiBillPaymentsAPI from '@qiwi/bill-payments-node-js-sdk';
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

@Injectable()
export class PaymentService {
    constructor(
        private readonly paymentRepository: PaymentRepository,
        private readonly rmqService: RMQService,
        private readonly configService: ConfigService
    ) { }

    public async getPaymentLink() {
        const qiwiApi = new QiwiBillPaymentsAPI(this.configService.get('SECRET_KEY'));
        const QIWISettings = {
            amount: 200,
            billId: qiwiApi.generateId(),
            comment: 'Оплата ЖКХ',
            currency: 'RUB',
            successUrl: 'http://test.ru/',
            expirationDateTime: '2023-09-12T19:44:07',
        }
        console.log(qiwiApi.createPaymentForm(QIWISettings))
    }
}
```

Собственно страница с ошибкой:

[image]